# Python optparse and spaces in an argument

Tags: python, optparse

When using optparse i want to get the whole string after an option, but I only get part of it up to the first space.

e.g.:

```
python myprog.py --executable python someOtherProg.py
```

What I get in 'executable' is just 'python'.

Is it possible to parse such lines using optparse or do you have to use argparse to do it?

€: I have already tried enclosing it in "s. But after digging further into the code I found out that the subprocess invocation can't handle the argument.

The string with the commandline gets crammed into a list 'args'.

```
args = [self.getExecutable()] + self.getArgs().split()
```

It's like

```
"[python D:\\\workspace\\\myprog\\\src\\\myprog.py]"
```

That gives me the System can't find file exception. When I use

```
args[0]
```

it works. But I loose the arguments to the executable.

The subprocess module builds a cmdline from a list if it does not get a string in the first place, so I can't explain that behavior at the moment.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can enclose them in quotes to make them work with the existing code.

```
python myprog.py --executable "python someOtherProg.py"
```

> Is it possible to parse such lines using optparse or do you have to use argparse to do it?

I don't know if/how you can do it with `optparse` as I haven't really worked with `optparse`.

I can however help you out with `argparse`. Here is a quick example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import argparse, sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = 'Demonstration of Argparse.')
    parser.add_argument('-e', '--executable', nargs = '+', help = 'List of executables')
    args = parser.parse_args(sys.argv[1:])
    print args.executable
```

And usage:

```
manoj@maruti:~$ python myprog.py --executable python someOtherProg.py
['python', 'someOtherProg.py']
```

I'd also recommend switching from `optparse` to [`argparse`](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html). `Optparse` is [deprecated](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html) since 2.7.

Answer (score 6):

I've found another good alternative `shlex` - A lexical analyzer class for simple shell-like syntaxes.

Source link: [How to parse a command line with regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197233/how-to-parse-a-command-line-with-regular-expressions/197305#197305)

```
>>> import shlex
>>> shlex.split('"param 1" param2 "param 3"')
['param 1', 'param2', 'param 3']
>>> shlex.split('"param 1" param2 "param 3"')
Traceback (most recent call last):
    [...]
ValueError: No closing quotation
>>> shlex.split('"param 1" param2 "param 3\\""')
['param 1', 'param2', 'param 3"']
```

Answer (score 4):

The behavior you see comes from the fact that it's your shell, not python, that parses the command line and separates it into the words of sys.argv.  Python is launched by the shell via exec() with argv already populated.

Most shells will split argv items at spaces unless you tell them not to by quoting or escaping.

Quotes work as described above.

In many shells you could do this:

```
python myprog.py --executable python\ someOtherProg.py
```

The backslash escapes the following space without requiring quotes.

Comment: Prepare to be stunned: under Python 3.5, an escaped space is unescaped by sys.argv !  In C, we have `silly python some` : `argv[1]` = `"python"`, `argv[2]` = `"some"`.  `silly "python some"` : `argv[1]` = `"python some"`.  And `silly python\ some` : `argv[1]` = `"python some"`.  But with Python 3.5 we have `silly.py python some` : `argv[1]` = `"python"`, `argv[2]` = `"some"`.  `silly.py "python some"` : `argv[1]` = `"python some"`.  And `silly.py python\ some` : `argv[1]` = `"python\\"`, `"some"`.  Amazing!

Answer (score 4):

If you know how many words after the argument flag you are going to get, you can modify the way you create the `--executable` option in in `optparse` to properly handle the situation:

Instead of taking a **single** word after the option flag you can set the `optparse` parser to look for **two** (or more) words:

```
from optparse import OptionParser
parser = OptionParser()

parser.add_option("-f", "--file", action="store", dest="filename",
                       help="File to be processed.", metavar="FILE")
parser.add_option("-e", "--executable", action="store", dest="my_exe",
                       help="Command to be executed", metavar="EXE",
                       nargs=2)
```

In this snippet, the `-f` or `--file` option only expects a single word and stores it as a string (the default) in the `filename` variable.

In contrast the `-e`, `--executable` option expects two words because of the `nargs=2` option.  This will result in the two words found behind the `-e` or `--executable` flag to be stored as strings in a Python list `my_exe`.

Check out: http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html for more info on `optparse`, and remember it has been deprecated as of 2.7 in favour of `argparse`.

Answer (score 1):

Just to finalize this answer list if you cannot upgrade to argparse.

**Optparse is not able to handle these situations** (multiple strings). You can only use nargs to specify particular amount of valiables, but there is nothing like "one or more". You **need to hack** it or **use different library** (e.g. argparse or other).

Comment: can you tell me how it can be handled using argparse ? w/o using `sys.argv` I guess argparse too doesn't have feature like to `parse_string` instead `parse_args`, e.g. to parse string having spaces like `"one or more"`

Comment: argparse is limited too, I don't have much experience with it :-(

Comment: see another solution provided by me, should work with `argparse` as well as `optparse` as its independent by using `shlex` lib.